# How to optimize input/output in C++

Tags: c++, performance

I'm solving a problem which requires very fast input/output. More precisely, the input data file will be up to 15MB. Is there a fast, way to read/print integer values.

*Note:* I don't know if it helps, but the input file has the following form:

- line 1: a number n
- line 2..n+1: three numbers a,b,c;
- line n+2: a number r
- line n+3..n+4+r: four numbers a,b,c,d

*Note 2:* The input file will be `stdin`.

**Edit:** Something like the following isn't fast enough:

```
void fast_scan(int &n) {
  char buffer[10];
  gets(buffer);
  n=atoi(buffer);
}

void fast_scan_three(int &a,int &b,int &c) {
  char buffval[3][20],buffer[60];
  gets(buffer);
  int n=strlen(buffer);
  int buffindex=0, curindex=0;
  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    if(!isdigit(buffer[i]) && !isspace(buffer[i]))break;
    if(isspace(buffer[i])) {
      buffindex++;
      curindex=0;
    } else {
      buffval[buffindex][curindex++]=buffer[i];
    }
  }
  a=atoi(buffval[0]);
  b=atoi(buffval[1]);
  c=atoi(buffval[2]);
}
```

Comment: Write your own method to parse input and write output (if you don't care about good coding practice and you are writing program to top the online judge). Normally, algorithm matters more than input/output optimization.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes, but how will i write it?

Comment: It's only 4-5 lines of code, write it yourself. Read the input into some buffer (fread/fgets), then parse the string into number.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I encourage you to try a solution using what you know, then if it's not fast enough of if you're struggling with one specific part, come back for help.

Comment: A state-machine tracking where you are in each phase of the read (n-def-line, n-lines after, r-def-line, r-lines after) would be near-trivial with the conditions you presented in this problem. Regarding *how* to write it, the word *trying* comes to mind, followed shortly by  *text editor*.

Comment: Keep us posted then! Edit your question with what you've tried once you're ready.

Comment: Have you measured the speed of the code you wrote? I doubt that those two functions are measurably faster than `scanf("%d", &n)` and `scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c)`, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General input/output optimization principle is **to perform as less I/O operations as possible reading/writing as much data as possible**.

So performance-aware solution typically looks like this:

1. Read all data from device into some buffer (using the principle mentioned above)
2. Process the data generating resulting data to some buffer (on place or another one)
3. Output results from buffer to device (using the principle mentioned above)

E.g. you could use [`std::basic_istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to input data by big chunks instead of doing it line by line. The similar idea with output - generate single string as result adding line feed symbols manually and output it at once.

Comment: He's using stdio, which is also buffered, so disk access should be minimized.

Comment: Nice one, but I would like to know if there is anything faster.

Comment: @Barmar In any case  any I/O function call has overhead which shall be minimized.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to minimize the physical I/O operation overhead, load the whole file into memory  by a technique called [memory mapped files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file). I doubt you'll get a noticable performance gain though. Parsing will most likely be a lot costlier.

Comment: This sounds interesting; are you aware of any (simple preferably)c++ implementations?

Comment: Actually, I would expect the parsing to be almost free, compared to the physical I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Put several input lines in a buffer, split them, and then parse them simultaneously in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using threads. Threading is useful for lots of things, but this is exactly the kind of problem that motivated the invention of threads.

The underlying idea is to separate the input, processing, and output, so these different operations can run in parallel. Do it right and you will see a significant speedup.

Have one thread doing close to pure input. It reads lines into a buffer of lines. Have a second thread do a quick pre-parse and organize the raw input into blocks. You have two things that need to be parsed, the line that contain the number of lines that contain triples and the line  that contains the number of lines that contain quads. This thread forms the raw input into blocks that are still mostly text. A third thread parses the triples and quads, re-forming the the input into fully parsed structures. Since the data are now organized into independent blocks, you can have multiple instances of this third operation so as to better take advantage of the multiple processors on your computer. Finally, other threads will operate on these fully-parsed structures. Note: It might be better to combine some of these operations, for example combining the input and pre-parsing operations into one thread.

Answer (score 0):

It's only 15MB. I would just slurp the whole thing into a memory buffer, then parse it.
The parsing looks something like this, approximately:

```
#define DIGIT(c)((c) >= '0' && (c) <= '9')
while(*p == ' ') p++;
if (DIGIT(*p)){
    a = 0;
    while(DIGIT(*p){
        a *= 10; a += (*p++ - '0');
    }
}
// and so on...
```

You should be able to write this kind of code in your sleep.

I don't know if that's any faster than `atoi`, but it's not fussing around figuring out where numbers begin and end. I would stay away from `scanf` because it goes through nine yards of figuring out its format string.

If you run this whole thing in a loop 1000 times and grab some stack samples, you should see that it is spending nearly 100% of its time reading in the file and generating output (which you didn't mention).
You just can't beat that.
If you do see that noticeable time is spent in the actual parsing, it might be possible to do overlapped I/O, but the machine would have to be really slow, or the I/O really fast (like from a solid state drive) before that would make sense.